# Manually change a cell value without breaking an infinite loop in a running macro?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to make a macro that has an infinite loop. in this loop, I change values of cells every second.

I want to manually change a cell without stopping the macro (Alpha variable in the code). Is there any workaround to make it possible ? or threads ?

here is my code :

```
    Sub test()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0

     Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
     Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
     Set P1 = ws.Range("A1")
     Set Q1 = ws.Range("A2")
     Set Alpha = ws.Range("G1")
On Error GoTo CleanExit

    If Target.Address = "$Q$21" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
    End If
CleanExit:

    Application.EnableEvents = True
        While i = 0

       P1.Value = 100 + WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 6)
           Q1.Value = Alpha

        Pause (1)

       Wend
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

and here is the Pause function:

```
Public Function Pause(NumberOfSeconds As Variant)
    On Error GoTo Error_GoTo

    Dim PauseTime As Variant
    Dim Start As Variant
    Dim Elapsed As Variant

    PauseTime = NumberOfSeconds
    Start = Timer
    Elapsed = 0
    Do While Timer < Start + PauseTime
        Elapsed = Elapsed + 1
        If Timer = 0 Then
            ' Crossing midnight
            PauseTime = PauseTime - Elapsed
            Start = 0
            Elapsed = 0
        End If
        DoEvents
    Loop

Exit_GoTo:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function
Error_GoTo:
    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description, Erl
    GoTo Exit_GoTo
End Function
```

When I select the cell, I get the Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error"

Basically, I want to simulate the functioning of hydraulic pump, there is an angle alpha that varies. If alpha changes the other parameters (pressure , flow ...) change. that's why I want to make a continuous loop on the parameter with some error every second(with the random function). When alpha changes (manually), The parameter change the value.That is the main Idea.

Comment: What happens now?  Does Excel lock up perhaps?

Comment: When I select a cell, I get the Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error"

Comment: Add `DoEvents` within the infinite loop, it allows you to gain control on UI, make changes etc. But not as responsive depends on how complicated you workbook is.

Comment: @PatricK, I ll try it and let you know.

Comment: @PatricK, The problem persists, when i try to select a cell and write in it. the macro stops, Is it possible to make Threads in vba Excel ?

Comment: Can you show full code and do you have `Option Explicit` at top of modules? `Target` seems to be inside Events Sub, is that true?

Comment: "I want to make a macro that has an infinite loop..."  No, you (99.999%) most likely don't.  Instead, you want a macro that listens for some event to be triggered, and run it when that occurs.  What's the overall idea here? Can you explain your goal a little more clearly?  Currently, it looks like you're just setting `Q1` to a bunch of values, looping all the time...is that just for a visual counter or something? What's `100-106` mean?

Comment: @BruceWayne, basically, I want to simulate the functioning of hydraulic pump, there is an angle alpha that varies, and if alpha changes the other parameters change. that's why I want to make a continuous change of the parameter with some error every second(with the random function) and when alpha changes I change the parameters.That is the main Idea. The Excel is then connected to a kepware Server via DDE protocol which is also connected to an Iot platform.

Comment: @PatricK, I edited my post and added the full code. I didn't add the Option Explicit on top of the modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For repeated Calculations using data from the worksheet I would use a construction like the following. It uses the `Application.OnTime` Event to run the procedure repeatedly (~ every second) until some condition is met (or a stop precedure is called). I used some simple code to show that you can enter data in the worksheet:

```
Option Explicit
Private Running As Boolean

Sub Start_Timer()
    Running = True
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1), "Timed_Code"
End Sub

Sub Stop_Timer()
    Running = False
End Sub

Sub Timed_Code()
    If [A1] = False Then Call Stop_Timer
    [C1] = [B1] + Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 6)

    If Running Then Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1), "Timed_Code"
End Sub
```